# Register own FieldType in Craft 3.x

Tags: craft3, php, fieldtypes, custom-fieldtype

I have the following struggle. I tried to register my FieldType in my init function of the module.php.

```
Event::on(
        Fields::class,
        Fields::EVENT_REGISTER_FIELD_TYPES,
        function(RegisterComponentTypesEvent $event) {
            $event->types[] = SweVolley_StaffelSelectFieldType::class;
        }
    );
```

The Class SweVolley_StaffelSelectFieldType.php exists in the folder: /modules/site/fields

The Error in the Browser:

Class "modules\site\Event" not found

I don't know why?

Comment: Did you import the event class at the top of your class (`use yii\base\Event;`)? Full example in this Knowledge Base article: https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/custom-module-events

Comment: Yes I have import the class yii\base\Event